# docker container pgadmin lock account

Tags: docker, pgadmin

Using linux platform,
running pgadmin image on docker, all worked fine.
after few bad login attemps , login is locked because of bad credentials.
is it optional to unlock ? and how ?

tried to increate MAX_LOGIN_ATTEPMTS,  unsuccessful attempt.